# Shift+Space not working in Powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-10-v1809

Since updating to Windows 10 v1809, pressing `Shift+Space` no longer sends a space in Powershell v5. If I use an older Windows 10 station (v1709), `Shift+Space` sends a space.

For example, I'm accustomed to pressing the following sequence of keys:

`g`, `c`, `i`, `Shift+Space`, `|`.

In v1803, this would result with `gci |`. In v1809, the result is `gci|`.

Is this key combination conflicting with something recently introduced? The problem is reproducible on multiple stations. If I'm working in a text editor, the problem doesn't exist. Launching PS with `-NoProfile` has no impact.

Additionally, this has only affected my installation of PS 5.1. In my installation of PS Core 6.0.2, `Shift+Space` still sends a space.

Comment: this thread could be the fix https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/9n9mh0/powershell_51_shiftspace_problem/

Comment: This resolved the problem. If you post the steps from the original reddit post as an answer, I'll be happy to accept as the answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems like you need to update the `PowerShellGet` and `PSReadLine` Module to make `shift+space` work again.

1. Open PowerShell as admin
2. Run `install-module -name powershellget -force`
3. Restart PowerShell (as admin)
4. Run `install-module -name psreadline -allowprerelease -force`
5. Restart PowerShell again

This should do it and it should work again.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/9n9mh0/powershell_51_shiftspace_problem/

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I didn't have to reinstall `powershellget` and I was able to install it only for the current user with the `-User` flag. (Also, I don't have a `-AllowPrerelease` parameter for `Install-Module`. Not sure if that's related to the `powershellget` install, but it worked fine without as of today.)

Comment: Yep, upgrading to 2.0.0 beta4 fixed it for me

Comment: The second `install-module` failed here with insufficient privileges. Yes, I'm a local administrator. Yes, I was running in an elevated Powershell. No matter, though, as I've got my shift-space sequence back, thank you.

Comment: Thank you, this has been annoying me for months because I very regularly am accidentally holding shift when I press space in prep to add a pipe!
For me, even running as admin, I also had to add `-scope CurrentUser` to get the `psreadline` to install, but its working perfectly after that.

Comment: I fixed this by only upgrading PSReadLine.

Answer (score 13):

This seems to be "broken" again in PowerShell 5.1.x. That is, `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler` shows no mapping associated with `Shift+Spacebar`, and pressing shift+space has no effect whatsoever.

Explicitly enabling it with `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Shift+Spacebar -Function SelfInsert` fixes the issue (pressing shift+space inserts space character), but the mapping will not show in the `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler` listing as is, but as plain `Space` mapping.

Comment: Upvoted this as it seems to be a (ahem) "better" fix than installing pre-release versions of modules